# I didn't do any exit passport control when leaving Japan. What should I do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, us-citizens, passport-stamps, visa-free-entry

I left Japan today on a 3 month tourist visa (I am a US citizen). I guess I was following some other people, or perhaps even I was just waved on, but I didn't speak with the exit passport controller when leaving Kansai International Airport. So, nobody scanned or stamped my passport to confirm that I was leaving. Was this a mistake, and if so, do I need to contact anybody and tell them that I am no longer in Japan? I plan on going back next year so I'd like to resolve any potential issues as soon as possible.

Comment: You can always contact your local japanese embassy.

Comment: @dattebane Make sure you keep proof of your date of exit eg your flight booking confirmation and your boarding card

Comment: I don’t remember how things are done in Japan (and it was a while ago anyway), but maybe they use the same techniques as the USA or the UK and rely on airlines providing the info to update their records rather than actual exit checks?

Comment: I don’t know if this is a reliable source but it does indicate that an exit stamp is required http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/kanri/gaikokuzin.html

Comment: @jcaron As someone who repeatedly flies out of Japan (and back): No, immigration officials check stuff themselves, there is systematic exit immigration. And knowing Kansai airport’s layout well, I am at a loss how OP’s situation could actually happen in practice …

Comment: Did you check every single page of your passport. What (while still unlikely) I find more likely than not beeing checked: the stamp might be on a different page?

Comment: @jcaron Even Japanese citizen are stamped.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I called the immigration office at KIX, and apparently, [as of about a week ago](https://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20190926/p2a/00m/0na/011000c), they are using automated facial recognition gates to quickly check out people staying on temporary visas, so I will not get a stamp. I had been to Japan multiple times before and got the stamp and spoke with an officer, hence my concern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to clarify, you *did* have your passport scanned by the machine on exit, yes?  Because your original Q implied that it was not.

Comment: Ah, I knew those booths existed but I didn’t know that foreigners are able to use them now so I discarded the idea ^^'

Comment: @jpatokal correct - I completely forgot about these gates because they are new, I was sleepy, and I specifically remembered skipping the controller guys on my way out. So I thought I literally just didn't do control.

Comment: I can confirm that using the automated gates, they don't stamp when on tourist permission, a procedure that seems new. In my case, two weeks ago, after the gate, there was still a desk with a guy that checked something (my passport or my face, I don't know).

Answer (score 47):

Managing to leave Japan without <s>an exit stamp or</s> having your passport inspected at all is **extremely irregular**, and I'm quite astonished that you managed to do so, especially by accident.  You are almost certainly registered as still being in Japan and, if you do nothing to fix this, likely to run into a lot of trouble the next time you visit.

Your best bet would likely to be to **contact the Immigration bureau at the airport you left from**, in your case Kansai (tel. +81-724-55-1453)  and ask for their guidance on how to sort this out.  Office contact details are available here: http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/info/

Per the site above individual information will not be disclosed by email, so you'll need to call, and I'd start by just stating that you noticed there's no exit stamp on your passport and.you wanted to confirm that your exit was correctly recorded.  However, in your shoes I would definitely insist on a written statement that this has been all sorted out.  I would also expect that they will -- with some justification -- blame *you* at least in part and more probably than not ask you to write a "*gomen nasai*" apology letter for (unwittingly) violating the law, but I would not expect other lasting consequences if your record is clean and your story otherwise checks out.

*Update:* The OP has clarified that they used the new automated exit gates, which indeed do not stamp your passport (and my bad for not remembering this, since I used one last month when I flew out of HND!).  However, using the gates most definitely *does* require scanning your passport, it's just done by a machine and not a human.

Comment: Caveat: It’s entirely possible that the immigration bureau speaks Japan and broken English only (never actually tried contacting the bureau but the officers at exit immigration are notoriously bad at even pronouncing the regular question ‘when do you intend to return?’ in English). If OP can get hold of *any* local person who can translate for them, that would be a big plus imho.

Comment: @Jan Per the website above, 4 languages including English are spoken.

Comment: I have been in Japan long enough to understand the difference between a written notice ‘English is spoken’ and people behind that notice actually being able to speak English ;)

Comment: @Jan Granted, but I'd imagine KIX can rustle up an English speaker or two.

Comment: Shouldn’t the responsibility be airport’s? How can even a passenger manage to do so without much effort? What about a bad guy?

Comment: @HankyPanky As noted, I find it rather astonishing that the OP managed to slip through, but I'll take their claim at face value.  The airport bears no responsibility since this apparently happened entirely in the area run by Immigration.

Comment: @HankyPanky there are audits that check for this kind of stuff, I can't remember the exact name of the situation but it happens..

Comment: This happens regularly for US military members: I entered through a normal airport (through immigration on orders) and left via military airlift years later (bypassing all Japanese controls)... although this makes me wonder if I should contact them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The airport was very empty when I left, so I must have just skipped over the passport control booth. I was very tired, I don't know. I will contact the embassy and the link you shared ASAP.

Comment: @Jan They can speak English, but only people who also learned English in the same Japanese school can understand what they say ;)

Comment: @dattebane You physically can’t ‘skip over’ them at KIX. You go down escalators and arrive in a ‘room’ the only way out of which is by going through the booths (or the automated checks which I don’t think you’re eligible to use). The booths have you walk up to the officer through a small gate, then you do a 90° turn, a few metres sideways before you get into the departure area, all in the officer’s plain, unobstructed view. I would take a photo when I’m there later today but pictures are expressively forbidden.

Comment: @Jan I know exactly where you're talking about, see my answer. Apparently they have a new system in place.

Answer (score 20):

As jpatokal says, you should contact the appropriate authorities in Japan. However, something else you should do is to collect evidence of your departure. If the Japanese authorities accuse you of overstaying, you should have evidence that you didn’t.

You should keep your boarding passes and any receipts from airport purchases etc. Perhaps your passport was stamped on arrival in another country after you left Japan.

If there is a Japanese embassy or consulate near you, you could go there in person in order to demonstrate unequivocally that you are no longer in Japan. Ask them to give you some written document saying that you were not in Japan on that date.